# GC not clearing objects in scope

Tags: java, java-8, jit

I had read an article long back and I dont seem to find it. It explained the below behavior where an object in scope might still not be cleared. In any case can you please help explain on why the below ends in `OutOfMemoryError`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<A> collect = null;
    int i=0;
    while(true){
        System.out.println(i++);
        collect = IntStream.range(0, 10_00_000).mapToObj(x -> new A(x + "")).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}

class A{
    String temp;
    A(String a){
        this.temp = a;
    }
}
```

When I put a `finalize` in `A` with a print statement, it is never printed. And the instance ends with `OOME` after few iterations. Why isn't `gc` clearing previously created `collect`. And the number of iterations as well is not constant, it ranges from `3` to even `100` but ultimately fails for `-Xmx500m`

Secondly for fun, I ran the above program with JIT disabled `-Djava.compiler=NONE`. And it runs forever as expected. How is JIT influencing it?

PS: When In include a `System.gc();` inside my while clause, it keeps running as expected.

Comment: try flushing the buffer after your System.out.

Comment: @MarshallTigerus That shouldnt have any impact. By the way, it flushes by defaul;t

Comment: It seems the main issue is that on every iteration you're creating a new 1m elems list, and deferencing the old list. Maybe calling `collect.clear()` and then `collect.addAll()` instead would mitigate that

Comment: @Everton Agner: it’s actually 3m objects, an `A` instance, a `String` instance and its encapsulated `char[]` array. Further, there’s a temporary `StringBuilder` and its encapsulated `char[]` array created for each `A`, making a total of 5m objects having only 2m immediately reclaimable. When `A` has the `finalize` method, [`Finalizer.register`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/lang/ref/Finalizer.java#86) will be called for each `A`, creating another object…

Comment: @Holger yep, I was focusing on the list itself, as only when the list would be collected all objects and their fields would follow...

Comment: @Holger A small correction: no StringBuilder (and no related char[]) is created with the default `-XX:+OptimizeStringConcat` optimization.

Comment: @apangin: I assume this optimization doesn’t apply to the first interpreted iterations and when the optimizer kicks in, all assumption about the temporary objects are moot anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can’t reproduce your result with `-Xmx500m`, but with `-Xmx200m`. Consistently, the program will fail when you add the `finalize()` method, as the finalizer is the *cause* of the problem. However, there *are* some `"finalized"` message printed in my system. Without the `finalize()` method, it runs perfectly forever (well, actually until I kill it).

There is no problem reclaiming the space of ordinary objects, but when you add a nontrivial `finalize()` method, you are actively preventing the objects from going out of scope, as they now must be enqueued for finalization.

While the JVM will always perform a garbage collection, trying to free all unused objects, before throwing an `OutOfMemoryError`, there is no such guaranty for objects hanging in the finalization queue. Slowing down the main task by disabling the JIT may indeed allow the finalization to process more elements. Keep in mind that having both, the main task and the finalize method printing to `System.out` has a synchronization effect which can make the timing of the processing critical.

The are several environmental aspects that can influence the outcome. Since there is no guaranty regarding which thread will execute a finalizer, the finalization can use all unused CPU cores (and your main thread uses only one).
Also the actual garbage collection algorithm (the JVM allows selecting one of several different algorithms) can have an impact.